# Definition of topological manifolds with dimension zero/locally euclidean of dimension zero

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

A topological $n$-manifold $M$ is locally Euclidean of dimension $n$ (each point of $M$ has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n)$.

But what does locally Euclidean of dimension 0 mean?

Comment: Discrete${}{}$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng What does that mean?

Comment: It means that "locally Euclidean of dimension zero" is equivalent to "discrete".

Comment: @LeeMosher A topological space $M$ is discrete if (and only if) every subset of $M$ is open, right?

Comment: @Filippo right, all subsets are open. However manifolds are requested to be second countable also, hence uncountable discrete spaces are not allowed.

Comment: @InsideOut Thank you :) Does this mean that a topological space $M$ is of dimension 0 if and only if it is a countable set endowed with the discrete topology (the set of all subsets of $M$)?

Comment: @filippo  is a...? did you miss something? Otherwise I don't get what you mean, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Bbb R^0$ is just a point, isn't it? Hence locally Euclidean of dimension zero means that locally homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^0=\{pt\}$. A $0-$topological manifold is then a countable set endowed with the discrete topology.

Comment: Only countable family **if** you have having a countable base as a part of the definition of a manifold. The OP might well not assume that.

Comment: Maybe we are using different definitions of manifolds. I have always assumed manifolds to be second-countable and then the existence of a countable basis. However, if we drop the second-countability condition also uncountable union of points endowed with the discrete topology are allowed.

Comment: I am currently reading John Lee's book about smooth manifolds and i just found the equation/definition $\mathbb{R}^0=\{0\}$ on page 25. Since $\{\{0\},\emptyset\}$ is the only existing topology on $\{0\}$, we can even make sense of the definition in my question for the case $n=0$ and we can prove what InsideOut said.